# How do I get enough reputation to reply to answers in Web Applications Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

See Title. I throw myself at the mercy of the internet. Are humans generally good?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please checkout [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and [ask].

Comment: Thanks, @Rubén. This was a shameless ploy to get 5 upvotes on the Web Applications stack exchange. I semi-succeeded.

Comment: While we love meta stuff -- besides this site, "we" have  [meta.se] --, asking meta questions might help you to get upvotes but will not to get reputation on [webapps.se]. I'm sorry for that. By the way, the body of the question might not help to achieve upvotes.

Comment: You don't reply to an answer. You are asking about adding a comment to an answer which is not the same thing - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/236563

Comment: @Chunmunka you may not reply to an answer, but I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I felt like this post could use at least one answer that is not a comment. Here's what we've learned.

**Per Rubén, the answer is found at this link:**
[What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

**Interesting Anecdote:**
One can use the "comment" feature to reply (or "respond") to answers.

[image: Proof of ability to respond to answers.]